# On Button Click dropdownlist to get refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have two dropdownlist, One for state and another for City. Also to add extra city there is another form, which opens in the new tab.

What i want is that, when I add the extra city for the respective state from the new tab. I want to refresh the **State dropdownlist** so that, I can fetch the extra city added when I select the respective State from the dropdownlist.

Please see the HTML code:-

```
<tr>
    <td class="td">Location/State</td>
    <td>
        <asp: DropDownList CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="ddlState" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="ddlState" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter State" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Someone suggested to use `UpdatePanel` but i was unable to use that. Please help

HTML for the city dropdown:

```
<tr>
                <td class="td">Location/City</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <a id="aExtraCity" href="AddCity.aspx" runat="server">Add City</a>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="reqLocation" ControlToValidate="ddlCity" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter City" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </td>
```

Also see the Code behind for the dropdownlist:-

```
public void LoadDropDowns()
{
    string country = "India";
    ddlCountry.SelectedValue = country;
    ddlCountry.Enabled = false;

    ddlMinExpYr.DataSource = Years;
    ddlMinExpYr.DataBind();
    ddlMaxExpYr.DataSource = Years;
    ddlMaxExpYr.DataBind();

    //populate states
    var states = _helper.GetStates(country);
    states.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    ddlState.DataSource = states;
    ddlState.DataBind();
}
```

AddCity code behind:-

```
protected void btnAddDropDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Add_CityforLocation";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CountryName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "India";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StateName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlState.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCity.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // BindContrydropdown();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);//You Can Haave Messagebox here
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ScriptKey", "alert('Your City has been Added.');window.location='Career_Job.aspx'; ", true);
}
```

Comment: And what are we supposed to do without seeing any actual code ? Also it would be of use to know what you've tried and what was the wrong outcome...

Comment: @Bartdude: See the updated question, but whenever i use to click on the refresh button it used to generate a new dropdwonlist..!!

Comment: If you don't happen to understand we might need some codebehind (C#, VB.NET,...) to at least have a clue on what you're doing wrong, I think it will be very hard for anybody to help you. But I see you already have 3 upvotes so I might be misunderstanding the whole thing...

Comment: @Bartdude: I am sorry for not providing details properly. See the updated question.

Comment: from a usability standpoint, why don't you focus on getting the city drop down to populate with the new city automatically selected instead of forcing the user to select state again?

Comment: @peroija: How can we achieve that, that would also be great.

Comment: @Bartdude: Any help or guidance related to this?

Comment: @RahulSutar you said you want to refresh State dropdown ? Shouldn't you update the city dropdownlist ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Yes, how to do that. I tried but couldn't achieved it

Comment: Why did you open a new tab for this ? i think it is better to use query dialog boxes . and using that you can get the new city details from the user and at the same time you can add those new values to your old form field.

Comment: @ArunPrasanth: Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Just go through this link http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/string.html, i think it will help you

Comment: Can you show AddCity.aspx markup and code, please?

Comment: You definately shouldn't open a new tab, popup will be much more usable and good looking practice. Please, see http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form it demonstrates pretty much the same functionality you need, except gridview is refreshed instead of dropdown.

Answer (score 5):

Updating the City drop down list without any events fired from the client can be done by implementing long polling or using frame works such as SignalR. A very similar question was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048324/how-to-auto-update-selected-item-in-dropdown-to-all-the-connected-clients-in-sig).

Here is an example in web forms using SignalR. Make sure you download and install **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR** from NuGet.

**Startup.cs changes**

```
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
    using Owin;
    public partial class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // map signalr hubs
        app.Map("/city", map => {
                             map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                             var config = new HubConfiguration() {
                                 EnableJSONP = true,
                                 EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
                             };

                             config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;


                             map.RunSignalR(config);
                         });

        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Here is a simple Hub which would take care of updating all subscribed clients with any new cities added.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

public class CityHub : Hub {
    // will be called from client side to send new city 
    // data to the client with drop down list
    public Task SendNewCity(string cityName) 
    {
        // dynamically typed method to update all clients
        return Clients.All.NewCityNotification(cityName);

    }

}
```

Here is a helper js script to create the connections to the Hub. Please note, this piece of code is from another example and I have included the license as well. Just create a JavaScript file somewhere in your solution and add this script. You will be using it on the client. *I added this under ~/Scripts/app.js*

**~/Scripts/app.js**

```js
/*!
 * ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.0.0
 * http://signalr.net/
 *
 * Copyright Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache 2.0
 * https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/LICENSE.md
 *
 */

/// <reference path="..\..\SignalR.Client.JS\Scripts\jquery-1.6.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.signalR.js" />
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />
    "use strict";

    if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
    }

    var signalR = $.signalR;

    function makeProxyCallback(hub, callback) {
        return function () {
            // Call the client hub method
            callback.apply(hub, $.makeArray(arguments));
        };
    }

    function registerHubProxies(instance, shouldSubscribe) {
        var key, hub, memberKey, memberValue, subscriptionMethod;

        for (key in instance) {
            if (instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                hub = instance[key];

                if (!(hub.hubName)) {
                    // Not a client hub
                    continue;
                }

                if (shouldSubscribe) {
                    // We want to subscribe to the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.on;
                } else {
                    // We want to unsubscribe from the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.off;
                }

                // Loop through all members on the hub and find client hub functions to subscribe/unsubscribe
                for (memberKey in hub.client) {
                    if (hub.client.hasOwnProperty(memberKey)) {
                        memberValue = hub.client[memberKey];

                        if (!$.isFunction(memberValue)) {
                            // Not a client hub function
                            continue;
                        }

                        subscriptionMethod.call(hub, memberKey, makeProxyCallback(hub, memberValue));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies = function () {
        var proxies = {};
        this.starting(function () {
            // Register the hub proxies as subscribed
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, true);

            this._registerSubscribedHubs();
        }).disconnected(function () {
            // Unsubscribe all hub proxies when we "disconnect".  This is to ensure that we do not re-add functional call backs.
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, false);
        });

        proxies.cityHub = this.createHubProxy('cityHub');
        proxies.cityHub.client = {};
        proxies.cityHub.server = {

            sendNewCity: function (message) {
                /// <summary>Calls the Send method on the server-side ChatHub hub.&#10;Returns a jQuery.Deferred() promise.</summary>
                /// <param name=\"message\" type=\"String\">Server side type is System.String</param>
                return proxies.cityHub.invoke.apply(proxies.cityHub, $.merge(["SendNewCity"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
            }
        };

        return proxies;
    };

    signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
    $.extend(signalR, signalR.hub.createHubProxies());

}(window.jQuery, window));
```

Here is a simple page where you have a single text input and a button to add a new City. Note, that you will need jquery, jquery.signalR, and the script above (/Scripts/app.js).

**AddNewCity.aspx**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/app.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var cityHub = $.connection.cityHub;
            $.connection.hub.url = "/city";
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#addCity").click(function () {
                    cityHub.server.sendNewCity($("#cityName").val())
                                        .fail(function (err) {
                                            alert(err);
                                        });
                    $("#text").val("").focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id ="cityName" type="text" placeholder="City name"/>
        <input id="addCity" type="button" value="Add City"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is **a separate page** where your City drop down list exists. This separate page will automatically be updated once you add a new city from the Add City page.

**CityDropDownList.aspx**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var cityHub = $.connection.cityHub;
            $.connection.hub.url = "/city";
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;

            cityHub.client.newCityNotification = newCityNotification;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                
            });

            function newCityNotification(city) {
                $("#cityddl").append($(getCityOptionItem(city)));
            }


            function getCityOptionItem(city) {
                return "<option>" + city + "</option>";
            }

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <select id="cityddl">
            <option id="0">Existing City</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested this myself and all seems to be working. You should end up with 2 separate pages, AddNewCity.aspx and CityDropDownList.aspx. Once you add a new city from AddNewCity.aspx, that value will get sent to the CityDropDownList.aspx and update the drop down list with the new city.

Comment: I dont want in MVC, i want in simple .NET

Comment: That specific example was in mvc (which btw is simple .net) you can perform the same task in Web forms. I will post an example for you shortly.

Comment: sure, will wait and implement..!!

Comment: This is not what I want. you are making my code more complicated. Anyways thanks for your effort. I will remove the downvote

Comment: This type of solution is the only option you have unless one of two changes are done. You either have to move the addition of the new city to the same page as the state and city drop down, Or you have to force the user to manually refresh the drop down by clicking a button or similar event. Both of which could be done using an update panel as suggested. Your original question explicitly stated the addition of the new city being done in a new page though.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use UpdatePanel. As trigger put the event that is adding a new city (maybe a button click)

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true">

        </asp:DropDownList> 
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonAdd" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

somewhere in the page

```
<asp:BUtton runeat="server" id="ButtonAdd"></asp:Button>
```

in codebehind of click button event add an element to the `ddTest` dropdownlist in this way

```
ddTest.Items.Add(new ListItem("CityName", "CityCode"));
```

In this way when you click the add button a new element to the dropdownlist will be added and the UI will be refreshed.

Comment: where should I add the button ? Inside or outside the Update Panel ?

Comment: the button could be outside the panel, I've added one row of code to show you how add elements to the dropdown. I can't add others because I don't know your project

Comment: I am getting error at `New` as it does not exist in the current context

Comment: it is not working, whenever I click on the button, it again generates the new dropdownlist same as State

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68861/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-faby).

Comment: still it is generating a dropdownlist

Comment: what do you mean with 'is generating a dropdownlist'? Which is the wrong behavior?

Comment: I mean to say, whenever I click on the button, it should refresh the dropdownlist. Now the behaviour after clicking is that it is generating a new dropdownlist with same data as `ddlState`

Comment: I need to explain you better, I think u did not got what is happening and what I want. Come on chat, I will explain u again the whole thing.

Comment: I can't chat now, try to explain what is happen in the question, then later I'll edit my answer if there is something that doesn't fit your needs

Comment: See, first of all.

I have 2 dropdown one of State and second for City. 

If I select the state and the respective city comes in the second dropdown. IF there is not the city which user wants to select with the existing city, he will click on the link beside the dropdownlist where he will be redirected to fill extra city.

When he finishes adding the extra city.He will come back on the same page, and he clicks on the button to refresh the state dropdownlist so that he can view the extra city added to the respective city. Do let me know if you need anything else

Comment: faby, anything u got ?

Comment: @RahulSutar yes i can.

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Do let me know what else you need from my side.. I have posted the question

Comment: Currently you are adding city from separate page .Can you add city from the same page ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad: The page is very lengthy, and also the page gets distracted, If adding in the same page will be easy than it would be great

Comment: Its up to you if you can add the code of add city in same page or not ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Yes, For now let the city logic to be added from the other page, my main issue is to resolve the dropdownlist. Please help in that.!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69117/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Do let me know once you free

Comment: @RahulSutar sorry rahul i m very busy these days.Will be free on thursday.

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Sure, I will wait for thursday. As I also have some other task. Do let me know once you free. Thanks :)

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Are you free now ? So we can finish it.

Comment: Not yet dude very busy.

Comment: @MairajAhmad: Are you free now ? I am waiting still for you.!

Answer (score 2):

You can open the "Add City" page in popup window (if you don't mind). And upon saving do something like that

```
Response.Write("<script>opener.RefreshDropDown('" + id  + "','" + val + "');</script>");
Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>");
```

and add some javascript like

```
function RefreshDropDown(val,txt)
    {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");            
        var sCtrl = document.getElementById('<%= ddlCity.ClientID %>').options.add(opt);
        opt.text = txt;
        opt.value = val;
}
```

Idea is from [Refresh parent dropdownlist from popup in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623479/refresh-parent-dropdownlist-from-popup-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: I think this should be accepted as answer, because Topic Started does not need to install additional extensions like SignalR. This keeps the task simple and pure. User shouldn't move to another tab to add new city - this is bad usability example and Topic Started makes his own life and development harder by implementing it in this way.

Comment: this seems to me to be the correct workaround/solution; however, this answer and the Linked SO question need to be better explained.  The recommendation here seems to be to load an aspx page into an iframe within a popup, is that correct?

Comment: Are you also recommending to attach/add an event listener to a button on the framed page that is in the domain of the parent page during the onload event OR are you saying the aspx page should do the response.write (calling those parent methods implicitly) during it's postback.

Comment: also, I prefer to be a bit more explicit when introducing uncommon objects like `window.opener`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener there's no reason to do it short hand.  I would do something like this (more or less) - `<script>var parentCallBackFunc = window.opener["RefreshDropDown"] ? window.opener.RefreshDropDown : function (args) {}; parentCallbackFunc({ "id": id, "text" : txt, "value" : val });`

Comment: If pop up blockers are of no concern and moving the logic into a popup page is an option, then this could work. However, with all solutions explained here, event validation from Asp.Net on the drop down page, if turned on, could detect that some additional arguments (the changed drop down item(s)) did not originate from the server. There are methods of triggering a server side refresh of an update panel from JavaScript which would eliminate that problem though. The other option would be to use an HTML drop down instead of the ASP one of course or to disable event validation (not suggested).